# How to filter rows based on value of XML atrribute name in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have table `Web.Log` with column `Properties` which contains following content

```
<properties>
  ...
  <property key="ActivityId" />
  <property key="UserName">John Doe</property>
</properties>
```

How can I filter `Web.Log` table only on rows, which contains `John Doe` userName property ?

Now I use

```
select * from Web.Log
where cast(Properties as nvarchar(max)) 
like '%<property key="UserName">John Doe</property>%'
```

which feels like workaround :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XQUERY and an `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT {Columns}
FROM Web.Log L
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM L.[Properties].nodes('/properties/property')p(p)
              WHERE p.p.value('(text())[1]','nvarchar(50)') = 'John Doe')
```

Comment: Larnu, it should be faster to use `XML.exist()`. Using `XML.nodes()` together with a WHERE will need to read the full set, just to check for the existance of one *key-value* pair...

Answer (score 2):

It should be faster to use the native XML method `.exist()`.

First create a *mockup scenario* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeText VARCHAR(100),Properties XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('John Doe exists'
                       ,'<properties>
                            <property key="ActivityId" />
                            <property key="UserName">John Doe</property>
                         </properties>')
                        ,('John Doe doesn''t exist'
                       ,'<properties>
                            <property key="ActivityId" />
                            <property key="UserName">Someone else</property>
                         </properties>')
                        ,('John Doe exists'
                       ,'<properties>
                            <property key="ActivityId" />
                            <property key="UserName">John Doe</property>
                         </properties>');
```

--We can use variables to filter generically

```
DECLARE @SearchFor VARCHAR(100)='UserName';
DECLARE @FindThis  VARCHAR(100)='John Doe';
```

--This is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl t 
WHERE t.Properties.exist('/properties/property[@key=sql:variable("@SearchFor") and text()[1]=sql:variable("@FindThis")]')=1;
```

The idea in short:

- We can use `.exist()` directly in the WHERE clause.
- The WHERE is TRUE, when there is at least one hit at the given XPath
- The `=1` can be set to `=0` in order to return the negative set
- The XPath uses a XQuery predicate to search for a `<property>` with the given key and value.